# Как работать с LoadRunner?

Tags: тестирование, highload, нагрузочное-тестирование

Задача провести нагрузочное тестирование почтовой системы.
На почту должно подключится 1000 юзеров одновременно, пройтись по сценарию (авторизоваться, написать письмо и др).
Я сделал скрипт по сценарий для одного юзера, все работает, а как быть с остальными юзерами?
Для них тоже создавать скрипт? Или можно все одним скриптом?
Как быть? 
Может я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Для них тоже создавать скрипт?

Для начала хватит одного. По крайней мере, для начала.

> Может я не так делаю?

Вы все правильно делаете. Только в модуле Controller Вам нужно установить количество виртуальных пользователей.